Can I build flutter packages
Question
Is it possible to build only a flutter package in release mode and then reference(link) it from the release build artifact of a flutter application(libapp.so)?
Target Env

Linux
flutter 3.10.6 or later

Background
I'm developing a flutter application(=appX). This application consists of some local flutter packages(=packageA, packageA').
packageA and packageA' provide the same interface but have different behavior. appX uses only one of packageA and packageA'.
Currently, dart-define variables determines whether to use packageA or packageA' when compiling appX.
However, I would like to switch between packageA and packageA' using the following procedure.(The reason why I want to do this is quite complicated, so I won't go into it here.)

Compile packageA and packageA' in release mode and create files with the same name (packageA-selected.so)
During installation, decide whether to use packageA.so or packageA'.so, and install the packageA-selected.so that is to be used.
libapp.so uses packageA-selected.so at startup.

I wanted to ask if such a procedure is possible.
Thank you!
